# Display byte array of image in imageview

Tags: android, android-layout, bitmap, bitmapfactory

I am trying to show byte array of image from server inside the image view of an android activity. I am able to get the byte array correctly as sent from the server, but while converting it into bitmap it is always returning null. I have used the BitmapFactory.decode(byteArray,0, byteArray.length) for converting image byte array to bitmap which is returning null always.

Please help me solving this and tell me if there are any alternative.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What image format is the data you receive from the server? The BitmapFactory decodeByteArray API is expecting 'compressed image data'  which suggests it wants e.g. JPEG/PNG/etc.

Comment: hi Jonathan thanks for reply, am using .png image format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well a better option is to use this. I used it to display images that is present on a server. Pretty fast

```
URL url = new URL(link);
InputStream picin = url.openStream();
Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(picin);
pic.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);
```

Where link points to the jpg image. Works for other image formats also.

Comment: thanks for reply... its working and i m able to show image from server in an image view of my activity. but i need to display BLOB image data from mysql database into the imageview is there any other way of doing this? please reply

Comment: Welcome Karthi, I guess  BitmapFactory is not compatible with BLOB type. So you may try to first convert your JPG and then render it.
Do a little bit of search on BLOB-to-JPG.